# Selecting rows based on conditions (column) using the comparison operator >

Tags: python, conditional-statements, rows

While discovering python, i found myself stuck trying to select rows (food items) based on values of a column (macro nutriments). My condition uses a relational operation and the output is not the correct. 
(particularly with the > or < operators not having the problem with the == operator).

```
data.loc[data['protein']=='10']
```

Result of my code sample

[image]

The result is correct because all the rows (food items) seem to have a protein of value 10.

```
data.loc[data['protein']>'10']
```

Result of my code sample

[image]

The result is incorrect because all the rows have a value that do not respect the condition given (you have rows with protein < 10 like you have rows with protein >10) .

```
data.loc[data['protein']>'10']
```

Any thoughts on the issue ? Do you think it's related with the file format (see code sample below) ? If so, how can i get around the problem ?

```
data = pd.read_excel('Documents/test.xlsx',names=col_names,usecols="D,E,F,G,H,J,M,N,P,Q,R,T,Y,Z,AA", index_col =[3]).
```

Thanks in advance and Happy Holidays !!

[EDITED]

**So did more digging, indeed i am comparing two different things. @Daniel Mesejo the type of protein is Object. Since i want to have the protein column in a float format, i decided to convert it into string first and then into float. Unfortunately converting it to string using the `.astype(str)` didn't work**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuDVf.png)

Comment: It's a string, not number. `'10'`.

Comment: In `data.loc[data['protein']>'10']`, you have '10' which is a string, so what you are saying give all the strings that come after the '10' (as a string). What is the type of protein?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: So did more digging, indeed i am comparing two different things. @Daniel Mesejo the type of protein is Object. So i said to myself that i have to convert the  column protein into float, but for me to do that i'll have to convert to string first then to float. Unfortunately converting it using the [.astype(str)] didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use `data['protein'] = data['protein'].astype('int64')` to convert string to integer and then retry what you were doing.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are comparing string rather than integers. Change `data.loc[data['protein']>'10']` for `data.loc[int(data['protein'])>10]`

Comment: Can you convert a series like that `int(data['protein'])`?

Comment: Just recheck with a pandas dataframe. The value inside is a series, not an `int`

Comment: You will end up with `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: Sure.. No problem.. :) Just pointed out, it's misleading in accordance to the question. It will be great if you update the answer.